# How do I refresh React state after running navigator.pop()?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

While working with React Native, I have a few components that are pushed on top of each other, some of which change the state of the component below them, like so:

Social -> Groups -> Add Group

However, when I run `navigator.pop()` to get back to the previous component (for example, after adding a group to a user's account), the component underneath (in this case, 'Groups') won't refresh with the latest state.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the navigator. You need to alter the state of the top component with will trigger a rerender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was able to solve this by inserting a `componentWillUpdate` on the 'Groups' component, that is, whenever the Groups component updates, it triggers a loadGroupsData function:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  this.loadGroupsData();
}
```

...to which the loadGroupsData function checks for any differences, and if any are present, it loads:

```
loadGroupsData() {
api.getUserGroups(this.state.userId, (data) => {
  data.forEach((group, index) => {
    group.groupname = group.groupname;
  });
  if (this.state.dataSource._cachedRowCount === undefined || this.state.dataSource._cachedRowCount !== data.length) {
    this.setState({
      usersGroups: data.map(data => data.groupname),
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
      loaded: true,
    });
  }
});}
```

Comment: I don't think you can setState in the componentWillUpdate function. The react native documentation says.
Note:
You cannot use this.setState() in this method. If you need to update state in response to a prop change, use componentWillReceiveProps instead. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: getting endless calls if I put setState on componentWillUpdate, any idea how to prevent this?